# how can import js file in head script of nuxt 3 configs?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt-auth

this is my error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtEXP.png)

i tried this ways and plugins doesn't work

```
{
  type: "text/javascript",
  src: "~/assets/js/kit.fontawesome.js",
},
{
  type: "text/javascript",
  src: "assets/js/kit.fontawesome.js",
},
{
  type: "text/javascript",
  src: "@/assets/js/kit.fontawesome.js",
},
{
  type: "text/javascript",
  src: "js/kit.fontawesome.js",
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use useHead on .vue page as well. But it should be the same as you do.
But if anyone else is interested:

```
<script setup>
    useHead({
        title: "Some title",
        script: [
            {
                src: "/_nuxt/assets/test.js",
            },
        ],
    });
</script>
```

The problem though you are facing is you are using wrong path. You need to use public path as I did in my example.

Or better, you can put your file into `public` folder let's say `test.js` file inside this folder will become `src: "/test.js"`.